# DAX Query - Filtering out values from a table in powerbi

Tags: dax

I'm using DAX to do some data analysis in powerbi. Very used to Python, bit lost with DAX.

What I'm trying to do is filter out values from a measure.

Currently the measure is like this,

```
Measure.Controllable = 
CALCULATE(
    countrows(table_adj_spec_uno), 
    table_adj_spec_uno[column_uno] = "variable 1",
    USERELATIONSHIP(
        'table_adj_spec_uno'[IncidentDate],
        'Table.Date'[DateOnly]
    )
)
```

I need to filter out this value from this table and column,

```
table_adj_spec_uno[column_two] <> BLANK()
```

and

```
table_adj_spec_uno[column_two] <> "Acceptance_mwap"
```

How do I count the rows, that include only the values with these things?

Also, if i want to return column two as a measure, without the values above, what DAX query am I looking for?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this below changes-

```
Measure.Controllable = 
CALCULATE(
    countrows(table_adj_spec_uno),
    table_adj_spec_uno[column_uno] = "variable 1",
    table_adj_spec_uno[column_two] <> BLANK(),
    table_adj_spec_uno[column_two] <> "Acceptance_mwap",    
    USERELATIONSHIP(
        'table_adj_spec_uno'[IncidentDate],
        'Table.Date'[DateOnly]
    )
)
```

OR

```
Measure.Controllable = 
CALCULATE(
    countrows(table_adj_spec_uno),
    KEEPFILTERS(table_adj_spec_uno[column_uno] = "variable 1"),
    KEEPFILTERS(table_adj_spec_uno[column_two] <> BLANK()),
    KEEPFILTERS(table_adj_spec_uno[column_two] <> "Acceptance_mwap"),    
    USERELATIONSHIP(
        'table_adj_spec_uno'[IncidentDate],
        'Table.Date'[DateOnly]
    )
)
```